# What is the difference between `esc_attr` and `_e`

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, escaping

I am currently expanding my understanding of WordPress, PHP and WooCommerce.

As part of my learning, I have taken an eCommerce theme, where I am 'playing around with it'.  It's chosen eCommerce platform is WooCommerce.

The theme has created an override for the `cart.php` template.  This file is currently out of date.  As per my learning curve, I am updating the files myself.

Whilst updating the `cart.php` file, I noticed that the WooCommerce default template had the line:

`<td class="product-name" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">`

whilst the theme's replacement line was:

`<td class="product-name" data-title="<?php _e( 'Product', 'theme-name' ); ?>">`

As you can see, WooCommerce's default template has the `esc_attr_e` entry whilst the theme has the `_e` entry.  Are they both interchangeable and as such, I can simply override the default with the theme's entry or are they significantly different?

Comment: Wordpress [`esc_attr()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_attr/) function is just a formatting function that allows to escape an attribute. But Wordpress [`_e()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_e/) is maid to display a translate text … The function `_e()` is the same thing than using `echo` with [`__()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/) … Now [`esc_attr_e()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_attr_e) is just like a mix of `_e()` and `esc_attr()`… Everything is in WP codex docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight from the WordPress Codex:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_e
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_attr_e

`_e()` - Displays the returned translated text from translate().

`esc_attr_e()` - Displays translated text that has been escaped for safe use in an attribute. Encodes < > & " ' (less than, greater than, ampersand, double quote, single quote). Will never double encode entities.